# Select statement that gives the names,ages, and counrty of birth when female but needs to give DateOfBirth as an age instead of DOB

Tags: sql, ms-access, date

So far I have:

Select FullName, DateOfBirth, CountryOfBirth 
FROM Students 
WHERE Gender = F

however I want the DateOfBirth to be Displayed as an age under an age heading.

Can I use this: (Datediff("yyyy",DateOfBirth,DATE())) if so where in my original statement would it go?

Comment: you have not shown your original table. your example function isn't runnable, so noone is going to be able to cut and paste this into their local db server console and run it. you also havnt said what database you are using. so you need to improve this question (the table, some insert of sample data, the query you have, the results it gives, the db versions you are using, ...). if not folks are going to come through and downvote your question for being low quality.

Comment: You've tagged this as mysql, but the DateDiff syntax looks more like MSSQL? Can you clarify which is correct.

Comment: SELECT FullName, DATEDIFF("yyyy", DateOfBirth, DATE()) As Age, CountryOfBirth
FROM Students
WHERE Gender = 'F'    is where im at now but i want the age to be calculated on days but am having trouble

Answer (score 0):

```
Select FullName, DATEDIFF(year,DateOfBirth,DATE()) , CountryOfBirth FROM Students WHERE Gender = F
```

You can modify the DATEDIFF function to calculate the age according to the date instead of just the year

Comment: SELECT FullName, DATEDIFF("DD", DateOfBirth, DATE())/365 As Age, CountryOfBirth
FROM Students
WHERE Gender = 'F'   is what ive used but it returns '#FUNC!' in the ages field, why is the happening?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the DateDiff function to achieve this. That function would replace the DateOfBirth column in the query, to become:

```
SELECT FullName, DATEDIFF(yyyy, DateOfBirth, DATE()) As Age, CountryOfBirth
FROM Students
WHERE Gender = F
```

Unfortunately, there is some contention around leap years in SQL. There isn't a straightforward way to deal with them. There's an updated statement below, but it awkwardly uses cases:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '1984-01-02'
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '2015-01-01'

Select Case
        When DatePart ( day, @startDate) <= DatePart (day , @endDate )
            Then DateDiff ( year, @startDate, @endDate)
        When DateDiff (year , @startDate , DateAdd (year , - 1, @endDate)) = - 1
            Then 0
        Else DateDiff (year , @startDate , DateAdd (year , - 1, @endDate))
    End As DoB
```

You may want to consider putting this DateOfBirth check into a Function for brevity/re-usability.

Comment: I have used your statement but wanted to modify it so the DOB not yet passed are not counted as having passed. How would i go about doing so?

Comment: Have updated for the current year, including checks for leap year

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use `datediff` with `yyyy` as that won't actually give you the ages correctly. It'll give you the years since the year they were born. If someone has a birthday later in the year than today then they'll be returned as a year older than they are.

What I would do is use `datediff` with `hour` or `day`:

```
datediff(day, DateOfBirth, DATE()) / 365
```

or

```
datediff(hour, DateOfBirth, DATE()) / (24 * 365)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper method for calculating age - an example is shown here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29127001/3527297