# Query Assistance with Selection

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm still working on a database project, and I've hit a wall where I'm trying to do something (probably not advanced) but I'm stumped!  I have two tables I've tried to join, ADLs and TENANTS.  In TENANTS, I need the following data from it: TenantID (PK)(auto-num), TenantDateOfBirth (date).

From ADLs I need: ADLID (PK)(auto-num), TenantID (FK) ADLDate (date), Eating (text with choices limited in a form to Independent or Has Difficulty), Bathing (Independent or Has Difficulty), Grooming (Independent or Has Difficulty), Dressing (Independent or Has Difficulty), and Transferring (Independent or Has Difficulty).

What I need is 4 separate queries.

1. query all tenants ages 18-61. - *Non-Elderly*
2. query all tenants ages 62+ who have all 4 fields as "Independent." - *Well Elderly
3. query all tenants ages 62+ who have 1-2 fields as "Has Difficulty." - *At Risk Elders*
4. query all tenants ages 62+ who have 3+ fields as "Has Difficulty." - *Frail Elders*

Comment: What field in ADLs has the TenantID as foreign key? Appears tables would be a 1-to-1 relationship so why have two tables and not just one?

Comment: I have TenantID as a FK in the ADLs Table.

Comment: Build queries that join on the PK/FK fields. Still wonder why you have two tables.

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result is much more useful than a textual description.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear on my tables.  Each tenant can have multiple records of ADL abilities based on different dates in time.  Kind of like multiple exam dates, which different ranges of difficulty per exam.  That's why I figured it made more sense to build two seperate tables.

Comment: You show 5 evaluation fields but state criteria of "all 4 fields"

Answer (score 1):

Join tables on PK/FK fields and calculate some fields.

Use `DateDiff("yyyy",TenantDateOfBirth,Date())` to calculate age. The calculation will round to whole year. For fraction of year try `DateDiff("m", TenantDateOfBirth, Date()) / 12` which rounds to month. Or consider a UDF. There are many examples out there - for a start [calculating age in years and months in Microsoft Access (2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124980/calculating-age-in-years-and-months-in-microsoft-access-2010) and http://www.blueclaw-db.com/vb_age_calculation.htm

Or suggestion from shawnt00 comment might be satisfactory:
`DateDiff("year", TenantDateOfBirth, Date()) - IIf(DatePart("y", Date()) < DatePart("y", TenantDateOfBirth), 1, 0)`

Calculate a difficulty factor:

`IIf(Eating="Has Difficulty",1,0) + IIf(Bathing="Has Difficulty",1,0) + IIf(Grooming="Has Difficulty",1,0) + IIf(Dressing="Has Difficulty",1,0) + IIf(Transferring="Has Difficulty",1,0) AS DiffLevel`

Apply filter criteria to calculated fields `<62` or `>61` along with `=0` or `<3` or `>2` - in whatever combination is appropriate.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "rounding". You can be one day apart and still in different years. Will this get you age? I don't have Access to try it out but I really don't think you necessarily need a complicated function: `datediff("year", <dob>, <today>) - iif(datepart("y", <today>) < datepart("y", <dob>),  1, 0)`

Comment: Correction to handle leap years correctly: `datediff("yyyy", <dob>, <today>) - iif(datepart("y", <today>) < datepart("y", <dob>) and datepart("y", dateadd("d", 306, <today>)) < datepart("y", dateadd("d", 306, <dob>)), 1, 0)`

Comment: But it calculates other birthdates wrong. My b/d is December and calculates my age to include 2018. It 'rounds' to full year.

Comment: My expression is wrong. I'll try to sit down in front of a computer and sort it out. As for ages in general, `datediff`()` doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm very interested to see how to format it correctly.  Thanks for the help everyone!  I'm very grateful for the chance to learn here!